# Using Pytest, How to check if aggregations returned by API endpoint are correct?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pytest-django

I have database which is connected to API endpoints. On query made between two date ranges, the API endpoints fetches data from database and performs some aggergation; Using pytest how to check if the aggregations returned are as expected?

Answer (score 1):

This is not anything special to pytest, no matter what tool you use, you'd need some [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_oracle) to check the API results against.

You don't mention any specifics, so my answer will be brief. One way you can do this is you directly connect to the database (e.g. with pyodbc) and execute a query that fetches the results. Then you compare what you got from the API and the DB. Of course, nothing's perfect, so you're still running the risk of writing a wrong query.